# Does it make sense to pass a dict together with a key to pass a storage location? Better way?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, storage

I would like to pass a storage container location to a class. Is there a better way to do it than by passing a dict and the key? Passing keys feels a little odd, though it seems to work.

```
class GuiWidget():
    def __init__(self, storageDict, storageDictKey):
        self.storageDict = storageDict
        self.storageDictKey = storageDictKey
    def inc(self):
        self.storageDict[self.storageDictKey] += 1  # in real problem store image

storage = {"k1":0, "k2":0}

w1 = GuiWidget(storage, "k1")
w2 = GuiWidget(storage, "k2")


# calls from gui thread
print storage
w1.inc()
print storage
w2.inc()
print storage

##{'k2': 0, 'k1': 0}
##{'k2': 0, 'k1': 1}
##{'k2': 1, 'k1': 1}
```

---edit---

Though I would do it a little more verbosely, I like Andrey's way. It works with either dict or list. It also gave me the idea for this solution with a class, though the differences in use seem more cosmetical:

```
class GuiWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, connector):
        self.connector = connector
    def inc(self):
        self.connector.v = (self.connector.v + 1)

class Connector(object):
    def __init__(self, container, key):
        self.container = container
        self.key = key
    def get_f(self):
        return self.container[self.key]
    def set_f(self, z):
        self.container[self.key] = z
    v = property(fget=get_f, fset=set_f)

storage = {"k1":0, "k2":0}
storageList = [0]

w1 = GuiWidget(Connector(storage, "k1"))
w2 = GuiWidget(Connector(storage, "k2"))
w3 = GuiWidget(Connector(storageList, 0))


# calls from gui thread
print storage
w1.inc()
print storage
w2.inc()
print storage
w3.inc()
print storageList

##{'k2': 0, 'k1': 0}
##{'k2': 0, 'k1': 1}
##{'k2': 1, 'k1': 1}
##[4]
```

All this reminds me of passing a pointer to a struct in C.

Comment: by now I realized, that even in this case where I thought there would be an exception to use a pointer like structure it really is better to pass functions. The reason for this is that it goes much better along with the principles of MVC. If you are using connectors/pointer like structures like above chances are you are doing to much in the Gui/the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to eliminate the dependence of your class on storage access method. That's my solution:

```
class GuiWidget():
    def __init__(self, accessFunc):
        self.accessFunc = accessFunc
    def inc(self):
        self.accessFunc(self.accessFunc() + 1)

storage = {"k1":0, "k2":0}

def getAccessFunc(key):
    return lambda v = None: v is not None and storage.update({key: v}) or storage[key]

w1 = GuiWidget(getAccessFunc("k1"))
w2 = GuiWidget(getAccessFunc("k2"))


# calls from gui thread
print storage
w1.inc()
print storage
w2.inc()
print storage
```